# how to tell windows to set lid action to do nothing in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

how to tell windows to set lid action to do nothing in C++
or to not to hibernate or sleep

like when you go to 
Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options
choose what lid closing action do 
and choose one of the 4 options but programmatically 
somthing like

```
SetLidaction(DO_NOTHING);
```

Comment: Close-voters: "in C++". This is *not* for Superuser, but really for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @deviantfan C++ is probably the wrong tool though. This is a sysadmin type task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [CallNtPowerInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372675(v=vs.85).aspx) with parameter `SystemPowerPolicyCurrent` to receive the current value of [SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373225(v=vs.85).aspx) and then change its `LidClose` and apply it back with the same [CallNtPowerInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372675(v=vs.85).aspx).